# is this possible to manipulate a description to same meaning but different words with data manipulation

Tags: selenium, artificial-intelligence

i want to copy a data from a website which sells courses like ITIL, Prince2 and PMP and many other IT sector courses now there are 20,000 different courses's description is there.

However, i want to use selenium to scrape all the data but description is still subject to copyright.

Kindly let me know how i can manipulate all of that description to data to same meaning but different words.

Is there any API which can give me an access to build an code which will be helping these description data by using it's synonymous or which can change it's grammer to completely new sentennces but same meaning.

Kindly let me know where to start this.

Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like a good topic for an ethical debate! Probably a [bit to broad or off topic for stack overflow...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Possible but can take a lot of effort and knowledge on Deep Learning/Machine learning. If you are lucky maybe you can get Already created algorithms to implement the same task. You can use semantic analysis to learn if your new sentence means the same and there are algorithm available for it. maybe some reverse engineering can help to create new sentences too.

Answer (score 0):

The task you are referring to is called **paraphrasing**.

There is a lot of research on the field. In [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/search/?query=paraphrase%20generation&searchtype=title&abstracts=show&order=-announced_date_first&size=50) you fill find research papers on the topic. However, since you are asking for an API, I am assuming you don't want to implement these models by your self. Luckily, some authors have [published their models online on GitHub](https://github.com/topics/paraphrase-generation). (Note: some are a re-implementation by someone else.)

When you use some of these implementations, note that most offer a **pre-trained model**. Do read which data set was used for training and try to pick the one that is the most similar to the data that you are facing. By doing so, more words in the domain of your descriptions will be available and more synonyms can be used.